# overriding a prompt for input in an ansible playbook

Tags: ansible

The following code except comes from a kubepsray playbook:

```
- hosts: etcd:k8s-cluster:calico-rr
  gather_facts: False
  vars_prompt:
    name: "reset_confirmation"
    prompt: "Are you sure you want to reset cluster state? Type 'yes' to reset your cluster."
    default: "no"
    private: no
```

Is there any way that I can run this such that the prompt is suppressed and it behaves as if a 'yes' was given for the prompt ?

I want to avoid having to edit the file.

Comment: Prompt fires only if the var is not set. Simply pass `-e reset_confirmation=yes` to your `ansible-playbook` command

Comment: I think that is it, if you submit this as the answer I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_prompts.html)

> Prompts for individual `vars_prompt` variables will be skipped for any variable that is already defined through the command line `--extra-vars` option, or when running from a non-interactive session (such as cron or Ansible Tower). See [Defining variables at runtime](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line).

`-e` being the shorcut option for `--extra-vars`, this basically gives in your specific case

```sh
ansible-playbook your_playbook.yml -e reset_confirmation=yes
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just comment out the prompt and set the variable to yes

```
- hosts: etcd:k8s-cluster:calico-rr
  gather_facts: False
   vars:
      restet_confirmation: "yes"
```

Sorry if formatting is off. Using mobile

Comment: Just updated my question, I want to avoid having to edit the file, I might be able to achieve what I want by adding -e reset_confirmation=yes to the command line.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to put that in the question originally but forgot.

Comment: https://www.devopsschool.com/blog/how-can-i-pass-variable-to-ansible-playbook-in-the-command-line/#:~:text=It%20is%20possible%20to%20set,one%20of%20the%20formats%20below.&text=If%20you%20are%20passing%20variables,vars%20flag%20to%20pass%20variables.

Comment: Above is a link with command line variable arguments. You could also try
echo yes | ansible-playbook args playbook